# Django Mysql not migrating models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, mysql-python

I'm learning Django, and I can't seem to migrate the model. The only thing that is being migrated is `ID`, although the model has `name`, `description`, `image` etc.

**models.py**

```python
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Destination(models.Model):
    name: models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price: models.IntegerField()
    desc: models.TextField()
    img: models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    special: models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Generated 0001_initial.py**

```python
# Generated by Django 3.0.6 on 2020-05-23 14:00

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Destination',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

**settings.py**

```python
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'python',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1q2w3e4r',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

**Migration output**

```python
$ python3 manage.py sqlmigrate travel 0001
--
-- Create model Destination
--
CREATE TABLE `travel_destination` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: You should write `name = `, not `name : ` (for all fields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class attributes are defined with an equation sign (`=`), *not* with a colon (`:`). So you write the models with:

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    # = instead of :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    desc = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    special = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Strange this works, im following a tutorial on youtube and the guy used : not = and it worked for him just fine. see you video min 0:54

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSbbYym79dw

Comment: @SalimAljayousi: what video. Somehow I often see people here following tutorials, but the quality seems to be quite poor of most tutorials. Often these people introduce antipatterns, like `request.POST or None`, naming `related_name` the same as the name of the field, etc. and then this often results in years of extra trouble.

Comment: @SalimAljayousi if you forward the video a bit you will see that he corrects the syntax to use `=`.

Comment: @SalimAljayousi: the video is also full of typo's. For example `defult`, and `max_lenght`. But indeed, as Niloct says, later the author fixes the problem https://youtu.be/dSbbYym79dw?t=73

Answer (score 0):

your models should look like this

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    desc = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    special = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```